# challenge response for RSA

Tags: rsa

I've got a homework question asking to explain challenge-response in reference to RSA encryption and signatures. There really doesnt seem to be much or any explanations online. can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Basic Idea:** For simplicity, assume the server $S$ is trusted.

Then all the server has to do is to prove that it has the private key $(n,d)$ corresponding to its public key $(n,e)$ which is trusted, say, via a PKI.

The client uniformly generates a random value $X \in Z_n,$ keeps it private, and then encrypts it into $$Y=X^e ~(mod~n)$$ and sends $Y$ to the server. The server 
obtains $$Z=Y^d~(mod~n)=X^{ed}~(mod~n)$$ and sends $Y$ back to the client.

By the uniqueness of inverses modulo $\varphi(n)$ we know that $$ed\equiv 1~(mod~\varphi(n))$$ if and only if the private key is correct. Thus all the client needs to do is to check that $Z$ equals the original $X$ it had generated.

I have used plain RSA with no randomisation or encapsulation. There are many wrinkles if we want to protect against replay attacks, etc., but your question sounds like a basic question.

**Edit:** (Thanks to @fgrieu) copied for completeness of answer, hope he/she doesn't mind.

> In challenge/response, the answer's server is more generally known as
>   prover; and the answer's client as verifier. The question also hints
>   at using RSA signature for that: verifier generates and sends random
>   $X;$ prover signs it as $Y=X^d~(mod~n)$ and sends signature $Y$;
>   verifier computes $Z=Y^e~(mod~n)$ and verifies that $Z=X.$ The
>   answer's method given above uses encryption, with the advantage that $X$
>   is not known to attackers and can be used to derive a shared secret
>   key. But the signature method allows $Z$ to carry information that the
>   prover has signed.

Comment: I believe `and sends Y back to the client` should be `and sends Z back to the client`?

Comment: I agree with Dan.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `and sends the original X(now Z) to the client` ?